# Sqlite - "Like" statement prepare c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to make a query for a database of families to search for a member by first name.

I am having trouble building a query using the "like" statement.
When I do it (as in the example below), it says incomplete input:

```
const char* request = "SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE firstName LIKE ?% ";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, request , strlen(request), &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "someName", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

When I put quotes in the query (as in the example below), it still doesn't work, and the error box says "column index out of range":

```
const char* request = "SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE firstName LIKE '?%' ";
```

I tried to do it without a percent sign, but the query just returns an empty result, how could I properly prepare a sqlite query with the "like" statement to search in a database?

Comment: use `?` and set your string value to `someName%`

Comment: Thanks that helped, it was an easy solution

Comment: Or change the query to `LIKE ? || '%'` (in case you are not aware, `||` is the string concatenation operator)